# Use ajax to communicate with existing node script

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, argv

I have a node scrip that I have written that currently takes command line params via process.argv, is there an easy way to be able to execute this script via ajax, i.e how do I get params from ajax to be interpreted as arguments, do I need to use a http node server?

Comment: take a look at either express.js or sails.js

Comment: There is no easy way and there won't be since it may generate lots of security issues. You have to write your own web server for that.

Comment: Yes, you will need to use some kind of web server. Whether that would be a node server or some basic CGI server that simply calls your script doesn't really matter; choose what you like best.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go for node with express js